# Преобразовать строку в ассоциативный массив

Tags: php

Есть пара координат в виде строки в таком формате:

```
$var = "-37.885309, -145.080471"
```

Обе координаты могут быть как положительными так и отрицательными. Как я могу преобразовать их в массив такого вида:

```
 array (
   'lat' => -37.885309,
   'lng' => -145.080471
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Разбираем строку по разделителю ", " (запятая, пробел)

```
$var = "-37.885309, -145.080471";
$arr = explode(', ', $var);

$result = [
  'lat' => $arr[0],
  'lng' => $arr[1]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$var = "-37.885309, -145.080471";

$result = array_combine(   //берем ключи из первого массива и значения из второго
    ['lat', 'lng'], 
    array_map(                            //преобразуем в число
        'floatval', explode(',', $var)    //разбиваем по запятой
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = "-37.885309, -145.080471, -37.885309, -145.080471, -37.885309, -145.080471";
$var = explode(', ', $var);

$len = count($var);

$result = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $len;) {
  $result [] = [
    'lat' => $var[$i],
    'lng' => $var[$i+1]
  ];

  $i+=2;
}
```

[Посмотреть результат работы](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/170bfa8a9207912938b49ab40f10c838ecbeae68).

Answer (score 0):

```php
$var = "-37.885309, -145.080471";

//Значения преобразуются в float.

[$lat, $lng] = array_map('floatval', explode(',', $var)); 

// Без array_map будут строкой

[$lat, $lng] = explode(',', $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Преобразуем, используя запятую как разделитель, входную строку в массив значений и комбинируем его с массивом заданных ключей:

```
$result = array_combine(array('lat', 'long'), explode(', ', $var));
```